# LoadRunner Controller: Need to Split up Parameter File

Tags: loadrunner

Background: We have a VuGen script we inherited that does exactly what we need. It uses a parameter file with all the data, i.e., some 30K+ rows. However, we need to run it across, say 10-20 virtual users, each with a share of those 30K rows. I'm new to LR so we're not sure how to set that up in the Controller. For example, do I need to split the input (parameter) file into, N different files and have N v-users run each of them? I'm just not sure how to set this up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have memory issues as each user loads a copy of the data.

As you are new to LR, I will refer you to your training material regarding parameterization which includes a lab with just this very question, on unique distribution of data for users within a group

I would recommend moving the one file to Virtual Table Server OR a cloud-based queue solution OR RabbitMQ, then feeding all users off of the queue

Comment: Did you know, if you load a parameters file within a group in DevWeb, it will be loaded only once and the DevWeb runtime engine will split the file between the users as needed. This is also true for any "read" file operations done via the SDK!

Comment: Now THAT is an innovation that HP should have completed a decade ago....if they weren't insisting in bundled deals that the hardware group have full comp and the bundled software groups fight to split the rest